# Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..4: 5

Tags: flutter, dart, compiler-errors, runtime-error

im getting strange error. I want to create a widget for every cell in a list, but when I write "itemCount: RemindTitle.length" I have that red screen.
It appears even when I enter just 1, 2 or any Int number

The second issue is that I have a Time Picker, but when I want to output numbers I've entered, it shows just random numbers, like 0 min, 30hrs

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: HomePage());
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  var RemindTitle = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "sdf"],
      RemindText = ["TexttF", "TextS", "TextT", "TextFr", "sdf"];
  var Counter = -1;
  DateTime? date;
  TimeOfDay _time = TimeOfDay.now();
  var DateText = "Enter the date", ChosenTime = " ";

  bool AlreadyBuilt = false;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          itemCount: RemindTitle.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            if(AlreadyBuilt == false) {
              AlreadyBuilt = true;
              return Row(
                children: [
                Expanded(
                flex: 4,
                child: Container(
                  height: 75,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text("Add Remind"),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return Container(
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Column(children: [
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                                        Expanded(
                                            child: ElevatedButton(
                                                onPressed: () async {
                                                  date = await showDatePicker(
                                                    context: context,
                                                    initialDate:
                                                    new DateTime.now(),
                                                    firstDate:
                                                    new DateTime(2015),
                                                    lastDate:
                                                    new DateTime(2030),
                                                  );
                                                },
                                                child: Text("Enter the date"))),
                                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                                        Expanded(
                                            child: ElevatedButton(
                                                onPressed: () async {
                                                  showTimePicker(
                                                      context: context,
                                                      initialTime:
                                                      TimeOfDay.now())
                                                      .then((value) {
                                                    setState(() {
                                                      _time = value!;
                                                    });
                                                  });
                                                  if (date != null) {
                                                    ChosenTime =
                                                        "Chosen time: " +
                                                            date!.day
                                                                .toString() +
                                                            ":" +
                                                            date!.month
                                                                .toString() +
                                                            ":" +
                                                            date!.year
                                                                .toString() +
                                                            ", time: " + _time.minute.toString() +
                                                            ":" +
                                                            _time.hour
                                                                .toString();
                                                  }
                                                },
                                                child: Text("Enter the time"))),
                                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                                    Text(ChosenTime)
                                  ]),
                                ));
                          });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0)),
            Expanded(
            flex: 4,
            child: Container(
            height: 75,
            child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Center(
            child: Text("Delete Remind"),
            )),
            ),
            )
            ],
            );
            }

            if(Counter < RemindTitle.length){
              Counter++;
            }
              return Container(
                height: 130,
                width: 175,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Center(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10)),
                          Text(
                            RemindTitle[Counter],
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10)),
                          Text(RemindText[Counter])
                        ],
                      ),
                    )),
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
              );
          }),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: (Text("Reminder :)")),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Red Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvxwj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your remindTitle length is 5 and you are trying to access the 6th item which is not available. And Time is also showing correctly. But you are displaying minutes at first and the hour which is in 24 hours format and setState is not working correctly inside the model, show whatever time you choose, it is always the current time when you press the button.

Hope this solves your problem.

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: const HomePage());
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<String> remindTitle = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "sdf"],
      remindText = ["TexttF", "TextS", "TextT", "TextFr", "sdf"];
  int counter = -1;
  DateTime? date;
  TimeOfDay _time = TimeOfDay.now();
  String dateText = "Enter the date", chosenTime = "";
  bool alreadyBuilt = false;

  showDateTime() {
    if (date != null) {
      int hour = _time.hour > 12
          ? _time.hour - 12
          : _time.hour;
      String meridian =
      _time.hour > 12
          ? "PM"
          : "AM";
      chosenTime =
      "Chosen Date: ${date!.day}:${date!.month < 10 ? '0' : ''}${date!.month}:${date!.year}, time: ${hour < 10 ? '0' : ''}$hour:${_time.minute} $meridian";
      setState((){});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 0),
            height: 100,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 4,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 75,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Text("Add Remind"),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return Center(
                                child: Column(children: [
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      const Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                                      Expanded(
                                          child: ElevatedButton(
                                              onPressed: () async {
                                                date = await showDatePicker(
                                                  context: context,
                                                  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                                                  firstDate: DateTime(2015),
                                                  lastDate: DateTime(2030),
                                                );
                                                showDateTime();
                                              },
                                              child: const Text(
                                                  "Enter the date"))),
                                      const Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                                      Expanded(
                                          child: ElevatedButton(
                                              onPressed: () async {
                                                showTimePicker(
                                                        context: context,
                                                        initialTime:
                                                            TimeOfDay.now())
                                                    .then((value) {
                                                  _time = value!;
                                                  showDateTime();
                                                });
                                              },
                                              child: const Text(
                                                  "Enter the time"))),
                                      const Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                                  Text(chosenTime)
                                ]),
                              );
                            });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0)),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 4,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 75,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Center(
                          child: Text("Delete Remind"),
                        )),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: ListView.builder(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                itemCount: remindTitle.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 130,
                    width: 175,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Center(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              const Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10)),
                              Text(
                                remindTitle[index],
                                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                              ),
                              const Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10)),
                              Text(remindText[index])
                            ],
                          ),
                        )),
                  );
                }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: (const Text("Reminder :)")),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, your code works, thanks.

Comment: But I have red screen that says "index should be less than 5: 5". That's what I was talking about, idk why it appears.
The problem is that this screen appeared even when I entered usual Int values such as 3, 4, 5. Doesn't work anyway

Comment: if the length is 5 the max index to use is 4, not 5. That's why you are getting the issue.

Comment: I get this red screen after I choose time. It appears even if itemscount = 5 or 4. That's the problem. Or it's emulator or flutter error?

Comment: When I enter itemscount = 5 it says "Index should be less than 5", same if I enter 4,  "Index should be less than 5"

Comment: you are getting the issue for your code or mine?

Comment: if(Counter < RemindTitle.length){Counter++;} this piece in your code tries to access the title array n+1th element at last. What is the purpose of having two returns inside itembuilder?

Comment: hope you changed the index property for both remindText and remindTitle.